# Restore a class/module to a virginal state

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am wondering how RSpec achieves this:

```
expect( MyObject ).to receive(:the_answer).and_return(42)
```

Does RSpec utilize `define_singleton_method` to inject `:the_answer` into `MyObject`?

That could work. Lets pretend this is what `MyObject` looks like:

```
class MyObject
    def self.the_answer
        21 * 2
    end
end
```

The *injected* `the_answer` method could contain something like  this:

```
@the_answer_called = true
42
```

However, how does RSpec then restore the class to its unmocked state? How does it restore it so `MyObject.the_answer` "truly" returns 42 again? (Via             `21 * 2`)

Since writing this question I'm thinking it doesn't. The class methods remain mocked until RSpec stops running.

However, (and this is the crux of the question) **how could one undo a define_singleton_method?**

I'm thinking the easiest way would be running `old_object = Object.dup` before `define_singleton_method` is utilized, but then, how do I restore `old_object` to `Object`?

That also doesn't strike me as efficient, when all I want to do is restore one class method. While this isn't a concern at the moment, maybe in the future I also want to keep certain instance variables inside `MyObject` intact. Is there a *non-hacky* way to duplicate the code (`21  * 2`) and redefine that as `the_answer` via `define_singleton_method` rather than completely replacing `Object`?

All ideas welcome, I definitely want to know how to make `Object` === `old_object` regardless.

Comment: Your example class shows an instance method, whilst the `expect` line and most of your question is about a class method.

Comment: Neil Slater Thankyou, I've corrected (I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSpec does not duplicate / replace the instance or its class. It dynamically removes the instance method and defines a new one. Here's how it works: (you can do the same for class methods)

Given your class `MyObject` and an instance `o`:

```
class MyObject
  def the_answer
    21 * 2
  end
end

o = MyObject.new
o.the_answer #=> 42
```

RSpec first saves the original method using [`Module#instance_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method). It returns an [`UnboundMethod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/UnboundMethod.html):

```
original_method = MyObject.instance_method(:the_answer)
#=> #<UnboundMethod: MyObject#the_answer>
```

it then removes the method using [`Module#remove_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-remove_method): (we have to use `send` here because `remove_method` is private).

```
MyObject.send(:remove_method, :the_answer)
```

and defines a new one using [`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method):

```
MyObject.send(:define_method, :the_answer) { 'foo' }
```

If you call `the_answer` now, you are instantly invoking the new method:

```
o.the_answer #=> "foo"
```

After the example, RSpec removes the new method

```
MyObject.send(:remove_method, :the_answer)
```

and restores the original one (`define_method` accepts either a block or a method):

```
MyObject.send(:define_method, :the_answer, original_method)
```

Calling the method works as expected:

```
o.the_answer #=> 42
```

RSpec's actual code is much more complex, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks very much! I trust you can use `<#Object>.method` in-place of `<#Object>.instance_method` to repeat these steps if `the_answer` is a class method? I missed out the `self` in my example, apologies :P

Comment: @JayTarka my example should work for class methods if you replace `MyObject` with `MyObject.singleton_class`, e.g. `MyObject.singleton_class.instance_method(:the_answer)`.